# How to switch screen unlock from Pattern to Slide

Tags: lock-screens, security, 5.0-lollipop, pattern-lock

On my Nexus 7 2013 Wi-Fi with Android 5.0.1 Lollipop I used the Slide setting for the lock screen. To experiment with a VPN, I switched to pattern lock.

After deleting the VPN entry I had created, I tried to switch back to Slide. However, the Slide and None options are grayed out and unusable under Settings -> Security -> Screen lock. Only the Pattern, PIN, and Password options are available.

How can I switch from Pattern to Slide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. **Open** your **Settings**.
2. Scroll down and select **Security**.
3. **Clear Credentials**.
4. Check the **Screen Lock** setting to see if the low-security options are now enabled.

If that doesn't work, you can revert your lockscreen security to *Slide*.

1. Set your lockscreen security to *Pattern* from **Settings>Security>Screen Lock**.
2. Click the **power** button on your phone to lock it.
3. Click the **power** button again, but don't unlock your phone. There should be a button labelled **Forgot Password**. *Note: On some devices, you may need to incorrectly enter the password/pattern several times until that option appears.*
4. Enter your Google account credentials.
5. Your lock settings should now be **Slide**. *Note: With this method, the option for* ***Slide*** *security will still by disabled, but you should still have it as the lockscreen security on your phone.*

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Sony Z3 Compact, stock Lollipop) it was sufficient to just remove VNP record to make swype unlock method available again.