# having problem with my lockscreen

Tags: system

I have tried everything,
Knox is on,
Android device manager is on and its still not working.

[image: help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was already answered [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/90059/79619):

> Try this:
>
> 1. **Open** your **Settings**.
> 2. Scroll down and select **Security**.
> 3. **Clear Credentials**.
> 4. Check the **Screen Lock** setting to see if the low-security options are now enabled.
>
> If that doesn't work, you can revert your lockscreen security to *Slide*.
>
> 1. Set your lockscreen security to *Pattern* from **Settings>Security>Screen Lock**.
> 2. Click the **power** button on your phone to lock it.
> 3. Click the **power** button again, but don't unlock your phone. There should be a button labelled **Forgot Passowrd**. *Note: On some devices, you may need to incorrectly enter the password/pattern several times until that option appears.*
> 4. Enter your Google account credentials.
> 5. Your lock settings should now be **Slide**.
>
> *Note: With this method, the option for* ***Slide*** *security will still by disabled, but you should still have it as the lockscreen security on your phone.*

Comment: Next time, flag as a duplicate instead of answering it again.